# Explain awk command `awk '{ if (NF > max) max = NF } END { print max }'

Tags: awk

In one on-line awk manual I have found example
`awk '{ if (NF > max) max = NF } END { print max }'`
    This program prints the maximum number of fields on any input line.
But I can't understand HOW awk does comparison `(NF > max)` if `"max"` just undefined string?? It can be 0 or 100 or 100,000? :-)

Comment: As an aside, the slightly shorter `awk 'NF > max { max = NF } END { print max }'` does the same thing.  In this case, the test used in the action can be used in a pattern, avoiding the need for an "if".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that on the first run through, `max` has no value. So the number of fields is greater than non-existent, and `max` is updated to reflect the number of fields in the first row. Each loop does the same check: "Does this row have more fields than our arbitrarily-named variable?" So by the time you get to the end, you know `max` reflects the maximum number of fields.

**Update**: @s.bandara's comment is spot on, and suggests that I probably should have pointed out the value of `max` more clearly. @Josh Caswell's answer gives some nice technical detail, so I'll just add a quick example that demonstrates his point:

```
echo '' | awk 'END {print (monkey=="")}' // true, an undefined variable is equal to the empty string
echo '' | awk 'END {print (monkey==0)}' // true, the numerical value of an undefined variable is 0
echo '' | awk 'END {print (monkey==biscuits)}' // true, one undefined variable is equal to another
echo '' | awk 'END {print (monkey=="test")}' // false
echo '' | awk 'END {print (monkey==4)}' // false
```

Comment: +1 for both the OP and @ajk. Not obvious that `3 > ""` should be true.

Comment: The variable exists -- it is actually created as soon as it's needed and initialized with the empty string by default, which is equivalent to numeric zero since it's used in a comparison context.

Answer (score 2):

A variable in `awk` [doesn't need to be declared or initialized before it is used](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_toc.html#TOC74). It will be created when it's needed. If it's not given a particular value, the default empty string will be used. The empty string is coerced to numeric zero in the context of comparison.

So in your code, `max` is created the first time it's referred to, the first time `if (NF > max)` is evaluated. After that, it exists and will be assigned to if the if test succeeds.